# android lollipop asynctask httpurlconnection

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to coding android program which send and receive data with web server.
And I'm using API 21(Lollipop).

So there is much problem with old codes.
One problem is that I can't use httpclient method, second problem is that connect to network code don't be included in main thread.

So I'm wandering web sites to make program which satisfy these conditions.

Below is source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity { 
    TabHost mTabHost = null; 
    String myId, myPWord, myTitle, mySubject, myResult; 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        mTabHost = getTabHost();          
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_1").setIndicator("send to server").setContent(R.id.page01)); 
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_2").setIndicator("receive from server").setContent(R.id.page02)); 
        findViewById(R.id.button_submit).setOnClickListener(buttonClick);  
    } 

    //------------------------------ 
    //    button Click 
    //------------------------------ 
    Button.OnClickListener buttonClick = new Button.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
           myId = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.edit_Id))).getText().toString();  
           myPWord = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.edit_pword))).getText().toString();  
           myTitle = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.edit_title))).getText().toString();  
           mySubject = ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.edit_subject))).getText().toString();  

           HttpPostData(); 
       } 
    };  

    private class serverconnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        protected String doInBackground(void){
            URL url = new URL("http://korea-com.org/foxmann/lesson01.php");       
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  

            int rescode = http.getResponseCode();
            if(rescode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

            }

            http.setDefaultUseCaches(false);                                            
            http.setDoInput(true);                        
            http.setDoOutput(true);                    
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");       
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            textView.setText(result);
        }

    }


    public void HttpPostData() { 
         try { 
              StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); 
              buffer.append("id").append("=").append(myId).append("&");                
              buffer.append("pword").append("=").append(myPWord).append("&");   
              buffer.append("title").append("=").append(myTitle).append("&");           
              buffer.append("subject").append("=").append(mySubject); 

              OutputStreamWriter outStream = new OutputStreamWriter(http.getOutputStream(), "EUC-KR"); 
              PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outStream); 
              writer.write(buffer.toString()); 
              writer.flush(); 

              InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(), "EUC-KR");  
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp); 
              StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
              String str; 
              while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {     
                   builder.append(str + "\n");                    
              } 
              myResult = builder.toString();                      
             ((TextView)(findViewById(R.id.text_result))).setText(myResult); 
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "receive_result_after_trasport", 0).show(); 
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
                // 
         } catch (IOException e) { 
                //  
         } // try 
    } // HttpPostData 
} // Activity
```

I'm pretty new to android. Any answer will be thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at RoboSpice for network requests, makes it dead handy: https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice

Comment: so why you cant use httpclient ?

Comment: lollipop doesn't support httpclient method

Comment: `second problem is that connect to network code don't be included in main thread.`. But that was already long before lollipop. Moreover i do not believe that HttpClient is not possible. I advice you to read some pages on this site. Posting to a website is about the most often asked problem. So do some searching and you find lots of good answers.